Seperate mail coming from addresses that specified multiple recipients
For a long time I wondered if there are ways to filter mail coming from e-mail addresses that specified multiple recipients, because somewhere in the headers there should be 1 recipient or 1>. One can specify multiple recipients or just 1. Let's say I don't want to have any mails from any domain in my inbox if it's coming from addresses that specified multiple recipients, but only 1.
For me, it could be a way to keep my inbox clean from spam and mails being addressed to multiple people, that's being interpreted as not-personal. Assuming I know who to communicate with, this will fits my needs.
I am not the owner of a mail server, and using the default mail app on iOS (IMAP) and the Outlook web interface.

This would need two rules :

Rule 1:   Mail "sent only to me" - and stop processing more rules
Rule 2:   Move all mail to a specified folder.

If you don't want to delete the emails, you could just set up a
conditional formatting rule that will color messages, to distinguish
them from the others.

I agree with the above scenario. You can distinguish between specific emails.

Okay I can make a condition "to:" and a property "is exactly:" with a value "my email address" but is it true that any server interprets property "is exactly" as ==1 repicent so when 1> repicents are being noticed from the mail headers the configured action will take place?  I'm asking because it has a  property "corresponds"  as well, but I am not sure which one to use.

If you set a condition where the “to:” field “is exactly:” your email address, the server will trigger the configured action only if the recipient’s email address matches yours exactly.

It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided? Any update would be appreciated.
